# In a PHP array for-each loop, how to execute not redundant loop data

Tags: php

I am trying to loop array string associated of the array inside the for each loop. The problem is redundant data display.

Here's my code data in array:

```
  $attr_xyz = array(
            

            'child_id'    => array('id_a','id_b','id_c'),
            'child_class' => array('class_a','class_b','class_c'),
            'labels'      => array('label_a','label_b','label_c'),

   );
```

*What I am doing is:*

```
$get_attr_label_id = [];
   
foreach ($attr_xyz['child_id'] as $child_id) 
 {  
      
       $get_attr_label_id[] = $child_id;
 }
 
$get_child_id = implode(" ", $get_attr_label_id);
```

```
$get_attr_label_ = [];
   
foreach ($attr_xyz['labels'] as $labels) 
 {  
      
       $get_attr_label_[] = $labels;
 }
 
$get_child_labels = implode(" ", $get_attr_label_);
```

Expecting output:

```
<div id="id_a">
<lable>$label_a</lable>
</div>

<div id="id_b">
<lable>$label_a</lable>
</div>

<div id="id_c">
<lable>$label_a</lable>
</div>
```

But what happen is:

```
<lable>$label_a</lable>
<div id="id_a" id="id_b" id="id_c"></div>
<div id="id_a" id="id_b" id="id_c"></div>
<div id="id_a" id="id_b" id="id_c"></div>

<lable>$label_b</lable>
<div id="id_a" id="id_b" id="id_c"></div>
<div id="id_a" id="id_b" id="id_c"></div>
<div id="id_a" id="id_b" id="id_c"></div>

<lable>$label_c</lable>
<div id="id_a" id="id_b" id="id_c"></div>
<div id="id_a" id="id_b" id="id_c"></div>
<div id="id_a" id="id_b" id="id_c"></div>
```

Comment: could you update your code and include how you're generating the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to iterate through the array and create new arrays. The original array already has a good structure.

This should do it:

```
$attr_xyz = [
    'child_id'    => array('id_a','id_b','id_c'),
    'child_class' => array('class_a','class_b','class_c'),
    'labels'      => array('label_a','label_b','label_c'),
];

foreach ($attr_xyz['child_id'] as $index => $id) {
?>
    <div id="<?= $id ?>">
        <lable><?= $attr_xyz['labels'][$index] ?></lable>
    </div>

<?php
}
```

*([Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/ju9K2))*

Since all the sub arrays are in order, we only need to iterate through one of them using `foreach`. That also gives us the array index to use when fetching the correlated values in the other sub arrays.

Comment: Perfect! thank you, expert Sir. Magnus, if you know how important what you did you the healer. Thank you very much very appreciated Have a grateful day. :))

Comment: @nielFernandez - No problem. Feel free to upvote the answer it as well, if you want :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$attr_xyz = array(
        'child_id'    => array('id_a','id_b','id_c'),
        'child_class' => array('class_a','class_b','class_c'),
        'labels'      => array('label_a','label_b','label_c'),
    );
    $get_attr_label_id = [];

for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) { 
    $get_attr_label_id[] = $attr_xyz['child_id'][$i] . " " . $attr_xyz['labels'][$i];

}
$get_attr = implode(" ", $get_attr_label_id);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<?php
$cntr = count($attr_xyz['child_id']) - 1;
for($x = 0; $x <= $cntr; $x++)
{
$child_id = $attr_xyz['child_id'][$x];
$label = $attr_xyz['labels'][$x];
//Print your html here
echo "<div id=\"$child_id\">\n
<label>$label</label>\n
</div>\n\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: your code is wrong. `foreach($x == 0; $x <= $cntr; $x++)` did you mean using the `for` loop ?

Comment: Sorry typo due to typing on mobile :)

Comment: `$x == 0;` should be `$x = 0;`. You want to assign the variable a value, not compare it.

Comment: Thank you very much, expert Sir. Keral Have a grateful day. :))